# When fetching an api in flutter, It showing Exception caught by widgets library Bad state: No element

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

what the actual problem is?

```
class Homenotifier extends ChangeNotifier {  

 Homerepositery _service = Homerepositery();

  List _getAllLocationdata = [];
 bool _loading = false;

 List get getAllocation => _getAllLocationdata;
 bool get loading => _loading;


    void setLoading(bool status) {
_loading = status;
notifyListeners();   
}
 
 Future getLocations() async {
try {
  setLoading(true);
  final response = await _service.getLocations();
  _getAllLocationdata = response["data"] as List;
  setLoading(false);
  log(_getAllLocationdata.runtimeType.toString());
  log(_getAllLocationdata.length.toString());
} catch (e) {
  setLoading(false);
  log(e.toString());
}
 }

  }
```

In view-part

```
      Class AllLocation extends StatefulWidget {
      const AllLocation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
     State<AllLocation> createState() => _AllLocationState();
       }

     class _AllLocationState extends State<AllLocation> {
   @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
  final provider = Provider.of<Homenotifier>(context, listen: false);
  provider.locationdatas;
});
super.initState();
   
  }




  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final provider = Provider.of<Homenotifier>(context, listen: false);
 return Scaffold(
  body: Expanded(
          child: Consumer<Homenotifier>(
            builder: (context, value, child) => value.loading
                ? const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )   
                : Card(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const Divider();
                      },
                      itemCount: provider.getAllocation.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => LiveCountView(
                                  datas: provider.getAllocation[index],
                                ),
                              ));
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                              height: 60,
                              child: Row(
                                //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                children: [
                                  const Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: Text(
                                        provider.getAllocation[index]
                                                ['zone']
                                            .toString(), 
                                        overflow: TextOverflow
                                            .ellipsis, //this one now works :)
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                              height: 60,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  const Text("MPC as on"),
                                  Text(
                                      "${provider.getAllocation[index]['date'].toString()} at ${provider.getAllocation[index]["time"]}")
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                              height: 50,
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(provider.getAllocation[index]
                                          ["count"]
                                      .toString())),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ),
```

Error showing like

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════  Bad state: No element The relevant error-causing widget was AllLocation".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ListView.separated() when fetching data from internet. always use futurebuider or stream builder, implementing those builder will fix your issue